# Vert.x unfair verticle redeployment after node crash

Tags: vert.x, vertx-verticle

I've been doing recently some experiments on the behavior of Vert.x and verticles in HA mode. I observed some weaknesses on how Vert.x dispatches the load on various nodes.

**1. One node in a cluster crashes**

Imagine a configuration with a cluster of some Vert.x nodes (say 4 or 5, 10, whatever), each having some hundreds or thousands verticles. If one node crashes, **only one** of the remaining nodes will restart all the verticles that had been deployed on the crashed node. Moreover, there is no guarantee that it will be the node with the smallest number of deployed verticles. This is unfair and in worst case, the same node would get all of the verticles from nodes that have crashed before, probably leading to a domino crash scenario.

**2. Adding a node to a heavily loaded cluster**

Adding a node to a heavily loaded cluster doesn't help to reduce the load on other nodes. Existing verticles are not *redistributed* on the new node and  new verticles are created on the node that invokes the `vertx.deployVerticle()`.

While the first point allows, within some limits, high availability, the second point breaks the promise of *simple* horizontal scalability.

I may be very possibly wrong: I may have misunderstood something or my configurations are maybe faulty. This question is about confirming this behavior and your advises about how to cope with it or point out my errors. Thanks in for your feedback.

This is how I create my `vertx` object:

```java
    VertxOptions opts = new VertxOptions()
      .setHAEnabled(true)
      ;

    // start vertx in cluster mode
    Vertx.clusteredVertx(opts, vx_ar -> {
        if (vx_ar.failed()) {
          ...
        }
        else {
          vertx = vertx = vx_ar.result();
          ...
        }
    });
```

and this is how I create my verticles:

```
   DeploymentOptions depOpt = new DeploymentOptions()
      .setInstances(1).setConfig(prm).setHa(true);

    // deploy the verticle
    vertx
      .deployVerticle("MyVerticle", depOpt, ar -> {
          if(ar.succeeded()) {
            ...
          }
          else {
            ...
          }
    });
```

**EDIT on 12/25/2019**: After reading Alexey's comments, I believe I probably wasn't clear.

1. By **promise of simple horizontal scalability** I wasn't meaning that redistributing load upon insertion of a
   new node is simple. I was meaning Vert.x promise to the developer that
   what he needs to do to have his application to scale horizontally would be
   simple. *Scale* is the very first argument on Vert.x home page, but, you're right, after re-reading carefully there's nothing about horizontal scaling on newly added nodes. I believe I was too much influenced by Elixir or Erlang. Maybe Akka provides this on the JVM, but I didn't try.
2. Regarding second comment, it's not (only) about the number of requests per second. The load I'm considering here is just the number of verticles "that are doing nothing else that waiting for a message". In a further experiment I can will make this verticle do some work and I will send an update. For the time being, imagine long living verticles that represent in memory actually connected  user sessions on a backend. The system runs on 3 (or whatever number) clustered nodes each hosting few thousands (or whatever more) of sessions/verticles. From this state, I added a new node and waited until it is fully integrated in the cluster. Then I killed one of the first 3 nodes. All verticles are restarted fine but **only on one node** which, moreover, is **not guaranteed** to be the "empty" one. The destination node seems actually to be chosen at random : I did several tests and I have even observed verticles from all killed nodes being restarted on the same node. On a real platform with sufficient load, that would probably lead to a global crash.

I believe that implementing in Vert.x a fair restart of verticles, ie, distribute the verticles on all remaining nodes based on a given measure of their load (CPU, RAM, #of verticles, ...) would be simpler (not simple) than redistributing the load on a newly inserted node as that would probably require the capability for a scheduler to "steal" verticles from another one.

Yet, on a production system, not being "protected" by some kind of fair distribution of workload on the cluster may lead to big issues and as Vert.x is quite mature I was surprised by the outcome of my experiments, thus thinking I was doing something wrong.

Comment: It seems you misunderstood what "simple horizontal scalability" is .It's just about ability to add more verticles at runtime, that eventually will handle messages. Redistributing the load is actually not "simple" at all.

Comment: Regarding the question itself, which is very broad, it doesn't seem that you're doing anything wrong, per see. But of course without knowing how may requests per second you're processing and what type of work they're doing, it's very hard to judge.